# Optimal gunicorn-worker configuration (number and class) for Python REST APIs

Tags: python, rest, concurrency, gunicorn, gevent

Lets say I have two conceptually different REST APIs developed in Python through a framework like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [Falcon](http://falconframework.org/) which I need to deploy through [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) on a server with 4GB of RAM and 2 vCPUs.

### API #1: CPU-bound

The requests to this API involve little to no IO but are rather CPU-bound. Nonetheless, the operations are very quick and require little memory, e.g., simple mathematical operations.

### API #2: IO-bound

The requests to this API involve a series of HTTP requests, e.g., to another API or fetching pages through GET requests. Thus, the majority of the 'work' involves waiting for other requests to resolve.

My question is: What would the optimal Gunicorn worker configurations (worker numbers and classes) be so that one would get optimal performance (preferably in terms of concurrency and requests-per-second) out of these APIs deployed on the aforementioned servers?

Reflexively I'd opt for a number of gevent-class workers but I've been scouring docs to verify said decision to no avail.

Any input would be appreciated :)

Comment: See https://medium.com/building-the-system/gunicorn-3-means-of-concurrency-efbb547674b7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you need two different things: parallelism and async.

The way Gunicorn handles requests is by allowing each worker to process one request. As such there is no "buffer" in front of the application to handle overflow and there is no solution to a possible "thundering herd" problem ([see here](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#choosing-a-worker-type)).

You will need to run 2 different gunicorn instances, each running one of the API's.

Ideally, you should have a ballpark estimation of your possible load for each API, because in your case parallelism is very limited (2 vcores are not much really) and as such, CPU will be a bottleneck for every worker.

Given the gunicorn documentation recommendations (2* nr of cores + 1) I would try to start from here, with the base assumption that it might overload the server:

```
#for API1
workers = 4
worker_class = sync
threads = 2

#for API2
workers = 10
worker_class = gevent
```

You will have to twist and tweak these values based on your server load, IO traffic and memory availability. You should test load response with a script designed to mock a flurry of simultaneous requests to both API's (you can use [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) for that).

Comment: thanks for the response! Quick q Re. API1: Will synchronous workers make it so that gunicorn 'queues' the requests as they come in? Won't a config like the proposed one just push-back on the requester saying "nope sorry no more resources"?

Comment: @somada141, made some edits to my answer, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: I am using fastapi with async functinos. so, i am using uvicorn workers with gunicorn. but during load-testing more than 46% of the requests fail and cpu usage never reaches past 30% for any of my 8T/4C cpu. how do i fix this? more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70912912/gunicorn-doesnt-use-all-cpu-resulting-in-lot-of-failed-requests